# Content type select field is not listing in front end

Tags: nodes, entities, 6

I created a content type field called  which have widget type **`select list`**  [image]

But its not displaying the field in frontend. When I changed the widget type to the **`text field`** it displays the field in frontend. I  given the `edit` and `view` permissions to the filed too

[image]

But its not displaying in the front end.

Answer (score 2):

when you create new field of type "list(text)" and then click "save"
you will go to new page where you have to insert the values you want the user to select from, add all the values in that page one value per line.
you can also assign key to the value by using this format "key|label"